# VHDL - does this signal latch?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have a module with `D_IN_VAL std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)` input port, and internal `signal CUR_MAX_S : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0)`. I wish to use only parts of `D_IN_VAL` data (e.g 4 bits out of 20 bit signal) so I figured I'll 'save' `D_IN_VAL` in `CUR_MAX_S` and then use parts of `CUR_MAX_S`. Ive assigned `D_IN_VAL` to `CUR_MAX_S` synchronously `if RISING_EDGE(CLK) then` and under certain conditions `if D_SEND = '1' AND WHAT_STATE = 0 then`.

But what happens when value of `D_IN_VAL` changes? Does the value of `CUR_MAX_S` change, too? Or does Quartus generate a latch, that remembers what Ive assigned to CUR_MAX_S? According to simulation, it 'remembers' the value, but Ive already learned not to trust simulation 100%. Its a signal and not variable, so I'm not sure.

EDIT: added example code, changed names of variables in question to match code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity MYMUX1 is
    generic (
    -- dlugosc rejestru jako potega 2-ki, nie mniej niz 3
    -- 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8, 2^4 = 16, 2^5 = 32, 2^6 = 64, 2^7 = 128, 2^8 = 256, 
        M : INTEGER := 4;
    -- szerokosc we/wy rejestru (w bitach)
        N : INTEGER := 5
    );
    port(
    -- wartosc maksimum
        D_IN_VAL    :   in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*N+M-1 downto 0);
    -- pozycja maksimum
        D_IN_POS :  in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(M+1 downto 0);
    -- wyslij nastepne dane
        D_SEND :        in STD_LOGIC;
    -- zegar, duh.
        CLK :       in STD_LOGIC;
    -- resET
        RST :           in STD_LOGIC;

    -- dane wyjsciowe, do UARTu
        D_OUT :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    -- dane gotowe
        D_RDY :         out STD_LOGIC;

    -- testowe
        test1 :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        test2 :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        test3 :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        test4 :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        test5 :     out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        test_state : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        test_neg :  out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*N+M-1 downto 0)
    );
end MYMUX1;

architecture AMYMUX1 of MYMUX1 is

    signal CUR_MAX_S : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2*N+M-1+4 downto 0);
    signal WHERE_MAX_S : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(M+1+4 downto 0);

    begin

    process(CLK)
    -- ile bajtow na wartosc? maks 4mln, 2^32. na przyklad n=12 bajtow, 2^m, m=8, 256 razy
    variable COUNT1 :       INTEGER range 0 to 7; 
    -- ile bajtow na pozycje? maks 65k, 2^16
    variable COUNT2 :       INTEGER range 0 to 3;
    variable COUNT_MAIN :   INTEGER range 0 to 11;
    variable CUR_MAX :      INTEGER range -(2**(2*N+M)) to (2**(2*N+M)-1);
    variable WHERE_MAX :    INTEGER range 0 to (2*2**M-1);
    variable WHAT_STATE :   INTEGER range 0 to 6; -- albo 6



    begin
--  if(RISING_EDGE(CLK)) then
        if(((2*N+M) mod 4)>0) then
            COUNT1 := ((2*N+M)/4)+1;
        else
            COUNT1 := (2*N+M)/4;
        end if;

        if(((M+1+1) mod 4)>0) then
            COUNT2 := ((M+1+1)/4)+1;
        else
            COUNT2 := (M+1+1)/4;
        end if; 

    if(RISING_EDGE(CLK)) then
        if(RST = '1') then
            WHAT_STATE := 0;
            test_state <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(0,4));
        else

        -- state 0 - jesli wartosc > od zera, zapisz, jesli mniejsza, odwroc i zapisz, wyslij ! jako znak poczatku paczki
            if(D_SEND = '1' AND WHAT_STATE = 0) then
                if(to_integer(signed(D_IN_VAL))>=0) then
                --  CUR_MAX := to_integer(signed(D_IN_VAL));
                    CUR_MAX_S <= "0000" & STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((signed(D_IN_VAL)));
                -- skocz od razu do wysylania danych
                    WHAT_STATE := 2;

                else
                --  CUR_MAX := -to_integer(signed(D_IN_VAL));
                    CUR_MAX_S <= "0000" & STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((-signed(D_IN_VAL)));
                -- wyslij znak a dopiero potem dane
                    WHAT_STATE := 1;

                end if;

                WHERE_MAX_S <= "0000" & D_IN_POS;

                test_neg <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(-signed(D_IN_VAL));
                WHERE_MAX := to_integer(signed(D_IN_POS));

                COUNT_MAIN := COUNT1;

                D_OUT <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(33,8));

                test1 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(CUR_MAX,12));
                test2 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(WHERE_MAX,12));
                test3 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(COUNT_MAIN,12));
                test4 <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(WHAT_STATE,12));
                test_state <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_signed(0,4));

            -- oba teoretycznie dzialaja, ale ktore jest poprawne...?
            --  CUR_MAX_S <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(CUR_MAX,14));
            --  CUR_MAX_S <= D_IN_VAL;

        -- state 1 - wyslij minus, jesli liczba jest ujemna
            elsif(WHAT_STATE = 1) then
-- and so on, and so forth... the rest of the code goes here.
```

Comment: You need to add a properly formatted example of your actual code.

Comment: Added part of the code that contains the part that's problematic for me - CUR_MAX_S <= "0000" & STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((signed(D_IN_VAL))); - will it latch and remain unchanged until I decide to override it? Or will it change, whenever D_IN_VAL changes? Also, any idea why those zeros ive concatenated display as XXXX in simulation instead of 0's?

Comment: *ZZZZ's, not XXXX's. Still, IDK why they dont just appear as 0000's

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description not your long code:

- `CUR_MAX_S` will be synthesized as n bit register with `CLK` signal routed to the clock inputs and output of the combinational logic `D_SEND = '1' AND WHAT_STATE = 0` routed to the enable inputs of each bit.
- The outputs will change after the rising edge of the clock signal, **if and only if** the enable signal is high, not when the input value changes.

That is the whole idea of registers: to store data when you want to, not when the input changes.